# Why is a Bastion Host more secure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, cloud

I've read that the best security practice for making EC2 instances Internet-accessible is to place them in a private VPC subnet, create a Bastion host in a public VPC subnet and use a security group to only allow connections from the Bastion Host and then do key forwarding to login to private instances.

However, it seems AWS offers various configurations which seem to provide similar functionality to an actual Bastion host. For instance using a Security group on a public subnet seems pretty good, and if someone gets access to your Bastion it seems likely that they're not far away from your private keys. In any case, is there anywhere I could find more info on this topic?

Answer (score 6):

It's a matter of minimizing attack surface.

With a bastion host your *only* exposure to the open internet (ex any load balancers) is port 22, which is backed by a [relatively trustworthy](https://www.openssh.com/security.html) piece of software.

It's also a single point of management: you define one security group that identifies IP addresses that are allowed to contact the bastion, and you create a single `authorized_keys` file that contains public keys of your authorized users. When a user leaves, you delete a line from each.

By comparison, if you rely solely on security groups to protect publicly-accessible hosts, you need to replicate the same settings on every group (and remove/update them as needed). And if you allow SSH access to those hosts, you have to distribute the `authorized_keys` file after every change.

Although I can't recommend doing this, it's at least rational to open port 22 on the bastion host for world access. If you have a lot of users, or those users connect via tethered cellphones, it may even be reasonable. That's something that you'd never, ever want to do with arbitrary services.

Answer (score 5):

You can find best practices of using Bastion Host here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/linux-bastion/architecture.html

> Access to the bastion hosts are locked down to known CIDR scopes for
>   ingress. This is achieved by associating the bastion instances with a
>   security group. The Quick Start creates a BastionSecurityGroup
>   resource for this purpose.
>
> Ports are limited to allow only the necessary access to the bastion
>   hosts. For Linux bastion hosts, TCP port 22 for SSH connections is
>   typically the only port allowed.

Note that it is pretty common to create an SSH tunnel to connect to a given resource through your Bastion Host: https://myopswork.com/transparent-ssh-tunnel-through-a-bastion-host-d1d864ddb9ae

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer this question in a more simple way.

First one needs to understand the bastion host (some people call it a jump box).

> The trick is that only one server, the bastion host, can be accessed via SSH from `THE INTERNET` (it should be restricted to a specific source IP address). All other servers can only be reached via `SSH` from the bastion host.

This approach has three security advantages:

1. You have only one entry point into your system, and that entry point does nothing but SSH. The chances of this box being hacked are small.
2. If one of your web servers, mail servers, FTP servers, and so on, is hacked, the attacker can’t jump from that server to all the other servers.
3. It’s important that the bastion host does nothing but SSH, to reduce the chance of it becoming a security risk

[image]
Hope this help to understand others!